# family of circles in bipolar coordinate system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, coordinate-systems

I don't get the idea how the equation for this family of curve is $\displaystyle  y^2 + (x - a \coth v)^2 = \frac{a^2}{\sinh ^2v}$ from [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates) on Wikipedia. Suppose, the equation is $\displaystyle y^2 + (x-h)^2 = r^2$, how do I parametrize $h$ and $r$? What points should I check to get in this form?

[image]

The circle seems to have radius $0$ when it passes through $(\pm a, 0)$ and infinite radius at $(0, 0)$. What would be equation of this family of curve in Cartesian coordinate?

Comment: So, what happened after trying the Cartesian-bipolar conversion formula on $\tau=c$?

Comment: @J.M. don't know never tried that (looks complicated), i believe it should have simple way of doing, for the other one seems obvious though as they both passes though $(-a,0)$ and $(a, 0)$. which reduces to $a^2 + a^2 k^2 = r^2$. For this particular, I can't find that it would have this form.

Comment: But, can you at least leverage the usual Pythagorean formula to eliminate $\sigma$?

Comment: @J.M. probably that definition follows from this curve relation. It's exactly opposite on my book. First the two curves and then transformation equations.

Comment: @J.M. looks like you are right!!

Comment: Nono, I meant something more fundamental: would $\cos^2\sigma+\sin^2\sigma=1$ be a useful formula? Anyway, if you've eventually figured the solution, please answer your own question.

Comment: @J.M. lol, I don't know if it would be useful, I thought eliminating $\sigma$ and $\tau$ from those two transformation relation and get the equation of curve in Cartesian form which doesn't seem easy.

Comment: Since **you already set $\tau$ to be constant**, you do not need to eliminate it; you should now get rid of $\sigma$, since that is the only free parameter remaining.

Comment: @J.M. probably it is wise to choose things this way, I did couple of plots on Mathematica `Manipulate[
 Plot[ {Sqrt[-(x - 2 Coth[a])^2 + 
     4 Csch[a]^2], -Sqrt[-(x - 2 Coth[a])^2 + 4 Csch[a]^2]}, {x, 0, 
   50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-25, 25}}, AspectRatio -> 1], {a, 
  0.01, 1.99}]` where the radius decay exponentially from $\infty \to 0$ from $0 \to a$ still, I think this is not so perfect choice as $(1 - \coth (v))^2 \neq \frac 1 {\sinh^2v}$ but since $v \to \infty$ both quantities are approximately equal. Well, perhaps that it is best way to model this thing.

Comment: You still haven't tried starting from the conversion equations. Again: try to solve for a trigonometric function of $\sigma$ for the $x$ and $y$ components, and use the Pythagorean relation to connect them.

Comment: @J.M. one is trig and another is hyperbolic, this got complicated to solve.

Comment: Well, you apparently did not see that you don't even need to touch the hyperbolic functions. For the $x$ component, you have $\cos\,\sigma$; for the $y$ component, $\sin\,\sigma$ and $\cos\,\sigma$. You are telling me you still can't solve for this?

Comment: @J.M. aren't these the transformation equation?
$$y = a \ \frac{\sin \sigma}{\cosh \tau - \cos \sigma} \\x = a \ \frac{\sinh \tau}{\cosh \tau - \cos \sigma}$$

Comment: That's just the $x$ component. Can you solve for $\cos\,\sigma$, or will you have to be helped in that matter as well?

Comment: @J.M. If I solve for $\cos \sigma $ I get it in $\tau$ and $y$, again if I replace, it in 2-nd equation, then still there is $\tau$

Comment: This is becoming tedious to repeat. Do you know what the label "$\tau$ **iso** surfaces" means?

Comment: @J.M. oh, $\tau$ is a constant for particular surface!!

Comment: **Finally**!! You set $\tau$ to be **constant**!! That's what I said earlier; you just didn't read what I said.

Comment: @J.M. No I read, but did not understand the underlying meaning behind it! thanks ... you have my regards.